# How can I remove the number in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to remove an option in the tooltip, I dont know if its possible
I have a function that set parameters of all my charts. I think I need to put it here:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: null
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2

        }
    }
});
```

I want to remove the part of the tooltip shown as 0 here.

[image: So you can see the infobubble appear when i put my cursor on a bar. i want to remove the number 0, he change in accordance with xAxis]

Thanks

Comment: Always try to post a [MCVE] when submitting a question to [SO].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the header text from your tooltip like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: null,
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

**API on headerFormat:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: i try this tomorrow, my server laging realy hard but thanks for your help